# How to replace json values from key-value map in GOlang

Tags: go

I have below json & I need to replace employee_names to emp_id from a map.

Tried this [GolangPlay](https://play.golang.org/p/WueFSW5CBkq) , but not sure how to replace values from the given map and error handling if the value is not present in given map.

Json data:

> ```
>     [
>   {
>     "dept": "IT",
>     "condition": {
>       "employee": [
>         "emp1"
>       ]
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "dept": "HR",
>     "condition": {
>       "employee": [
>         "emp2",
>         "emp3"
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> ]
> ```

Map data:

> [{emp1 14325} {emp3 49184} {emp2 21518}]

Expected output:

> ```
>    [
>   {
>     "dept": "IT",
>     "condition": {
>       "employee": [
>         14325
>       ]
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "dept": "HR",
>     "condition": {
>       "employee": [
>         21518,
>         49184
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> ]
> ```

code :

Started with below code , but not sure how to use the given map to replace with error handling.

```
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    //"strconv"
    //"log"
)

func main() {

    jsonStr := `[
      {
        "dept": "IT",
        "condition": {
          "employee": [
            "emp1"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "dept": "HR",
        "condition": {
          "employee": [
            "emp2",
            "emp3"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]`

    empMap := `[{emp1 14325} {emp3 49184} {emp2 21518}]`

    type GetEmployee []struct {
        Dept      string `json:"dept"`
        Condition struct {
            Employee []string `json:"employee"`
        } `json:"condition"`
    }

    var empResponse GetEmployee
    unmarshallingError := json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(jsonStr)), &empResponse)
    if unmarshallingError != nil {
        fmt.Println(unmarshallingError.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(empResponse)
    fmt.Println(empMap)

    for i := range empResponse {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }

}
```

Comment: @MuffinTop added now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the ids in an array of `{ids: value}`, it will be better for them to be in a map instead.

The above will range over the Employees' name and change it to the id. A check is made to see if there is a certain id key in the map.

```
for i, e := range empResponse {
        fmt.Println(e)
        for j,val := range empResponse[i].Condition.Employee {
          if _, ok := ids[val]; ok {
            empResponse[i].Condition.Employee[j] = ids[val]
          }
        }
    }
```

Full code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    //"strconv"
    //"log"
)

func main() {

    jsonStr := `[
      {
        "dept": "IT",
        "condition": {
          "employee": [
            "emp1"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "dept": "HR",
        "condition": {
          "employee": [
            "emp2",
            "emp3"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]`

    empMap := `{"emp1": "14325", "emp3": "49184", "emp2": "21518"}`

    type GetEmployee []struct {
        Dept      string `json:"dept"`
        Condition struct {
            Employee []string `json:"employee"`
        } `json:"condition"`
    }

    var empResponse GetEmployee
    var ids map[string]string
    unmarshallingError := json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(jsonStr)), &empResponse)
    if unmarshallingError != nil {
        fmt.Println(unmarshallingError.Error())
    }
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(empMap), &ids)
    fmt.Println(empResponse)
    fmt.Println(ids)

    for i, e := range empResponse {
        fmt.Println(e)
        for j,val := range empResponse[i].Condition.Employee {
          if _, ok := ids[val]; ok {
            empResponse[i].Condition.Employee[j] = ids[val]
          }
        }
    }
    
    fmt.Println(empResponse)

}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sbGE0c1dgpV)

In the above, the id are strings since the name to be replaced are strings. Actually `Employee` are of type `[]string`. If a string is to be replaced by an int, then Employee type needs to be changed to `[]interface{}`.

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aD1ZCz-DUOC)

Comment: Thanks . How to replace the replaced values as integer , is there any way to change the struct type while replacing "emp1" --> 14325 & not "14325" ?